# mobility scooter battery charger

Tags: batteries, charger

I have a mobility scooter that I put a Raspberry Pi and Arduino on to make a robot. I left all the original electronics in place so I didn't have to buy a motor controller.

I was able to charge the batteries with the original charger until I crossed a wire and blew a fuse on the control panel for the scooter. The charger was not connected when that happened so I'm pretty sure it wasn't damaged. Now the charger acts like it has no connection to the batteries. I'm assuming that the scooters controller is messed up. It still runs but won't let me charge it.

I looked at the charger and it has a XLR connection. I found some information online that says that those types of chargers have a positive and negative pin as well as another pin to stop the motor. I'd like to connect the charger directly to the batteries to see if it will charge. But I don't know what do to with the extra pin.

Anybody know something about this type of charger? The scooter is a pride sonic.
It's got two 12v 12Ah batteries in series. I tried connecting the extra pin to ground but the charger status never changed to charging.

Thanks for any information you may have.

Answer (score 1):

You might be out of luck. Batteries can't just charge when you apply a voltage; there are special current and voltage conditions that must be fulfilled in order to charge the battery, and these are met using special charging circuitry. If the battery charging circuitry is located on the board that you may have damaged and is damaged, the charger itself isn't going to be a whole lot of help. Usually, those large "brick" chargers that end in an XLR connector are just the DC power supply for the battery charging circuitry.